# How to enable and force Autoprefixer with Next.js?

Tags: sass, next.js, node-sass, postcss, autoprefixer

I'm trying to enable vendor prefixes with Next.js, but they're not working. I'm using SCSS modules, and tried also with normal CSS but this is not working.

EDIT: I'm using a custom PostCSS file:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
        [
            "postcss-preset-env",
            {
                autoprefixer: {
                    flexbox: true,
                    grid: "autoplace",
                },
                stage: 3,
                features: {
                    "custom-properties": true,
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

Comment: Autoprefixer already comes enabled by default in Next.js: [Customizing PostCSS Config](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config#default-behavior).

Comment: Yes I saw, but the generated CSS does not have the vendor prefixes. Do you know where it can come from or how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you using a custom PostCSS config file?

Comment: Yes, just posted it below

Comment: Same problem here. Does anybody know the solution about this??

Comment: I guess no one knows...

Answer (score 2):

You will just need to adjust the `browserslist` in your package.json.

```
{
  "browserslist":[
     ......
  ]

}
```

Try Visiting here for more info in `browserslist`:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist

Comment: Don't forget that the prefixes will be added when running npm run build